# R: Change Vector Output to Several Ranges

Tags: r, classification

I am using Jenks Natural Breaks via the BAMMtools package to segment my data in RStudio Version 1.0.153. The output is a vector that shows where the natural breaks occur in my data set, as such:

```
[1] 14999 41689 58415 79454 110184 200746
```

I would like to take the output above and create the ranges inferred by the breaks. Ex: `14999-41689, 41690-58415, 58416-79454, 79455-110184, 110185-200746`

Are there any functions that I can use in R Studio to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are looking to factorise then use cut function, see the help for cut.

Answer (score 1):

Input data

```
x <- c(14999, 41689, 58415, 79454, 110184, 200746)
```

If you want the ranges as characters you can do

```
y <- x; y[1] <- y[1] - 1 # First range given in question doesn't follow the pattern. Adjusting for that

paste(head(y, -1) + 1, tail(y, -1), sep = '-')
#[1] "14999-41689"   "41690-58415"   "58416-79454"   "79455-110184"  "110185-200746"
```

If you want a list of the actual sets of numbers in each range you can do

```
seqs <- Map(seq, head(y, -1) + 1, tail(y, -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create your own function that produces the exact output you're looking for, but you can use the `cut` function that will give you something like this:

```
# example vector
x = c(14999, 41689, 58415, 79454, 110184, 200746)

# use the vector and its values as breaks
ranges = cut(x, x, dig.lab = 6)

# see the levels
levels(ranges)
#[1] "(14999,41689]"   "(41689,58415]"   "(58415,79454]"   "(79454,110184]"  "(110184,200746]"
```